# Sending e-mails with curl from C++

Tags: c++, email, curl, cron

I wrote a small piece of code that sends a notification e-mail, here's the function that is responsible for sending it:

```
int send_mail(const char* mail_path) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode curl_code;
    FILE *message;
    message = fopen(mail_path, "r");
    struct curl_slist *recipients = NULL;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "XXXX");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "YYYY");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ZZZZ");
        recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, "XXXX");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, "XXX");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_ALL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, message);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

        curl_code = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        curl_slist_free_all(recipients);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    return curl_code;
}
```

It works fine when I'm using it from the command line.

It doesn't send an e-mail though when the script is executed via a cron manager on a remote server which I use. I can send the email properly via the server's cli too.

The code seems to stop working on the curl_easy_perform step, but I'm not sure why - what techniques can be useful to debug such kind of a problem?

Cron jobs are creating emails on their own too - could that be the cause of the problem?

Edit:

I checked the logs and it seems that in case of the cron manager the IP address of the google's smtp service that I'm trying to connect to is different than in case of a script that is run directly from the command line. The logs from cron end after `354 Go ahead`. Other than that the logs are the same.

cron:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587/
*   Trying 173.194.71.108...

...

> DATA
< 354  Go ahead ra7sm645322lbb.27 - gsmtp
---- stops here ----
```

command line:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587/
*   Trying 74.125.195.109...

...

< 354  Go ahead ex5sm4631837wib.2 - gsmtp
< 250 2.0.0 OK 1432828708 ex5sm4631837wib.2 - gsmtp
* Connection #0 to host smtp.gmail.com left intact
```

Answer (score 1):

1. switch on [CURLOPT_VERBOSE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_VERBOSE.html) to 1L
2. log the stderr for your failed attempts and study it after the failures

No, the fact that cronjobs send their own mails is not a reason for this code to fail.

Comment: Thank you, this brings me a little bit closer to the answer. I've updated my question after checking the logs, any ideas?